# Control Chart: Nelson alternating rule

Tags: r, probability, random-generation, quality-control

The [Nelson rules for control charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_rules) describe patterns, which are "special" and need our attention. One of these rules is the "alternation rule". According to Nelson it is "unusual" to obtain a series of 14 alternating points -- direction does not matter.

I tried to simulate the probability of such an event using a normal distribution. Here my code:

```
nSim  = 1e6
count = 0
n     = 14
iVec1 = seq(1, n, by=2)
iVec2 = iVec1 + 1
for (i in 1:nSim){
    tmp     = rnorm(n)
    sumSide = sum( tmp[iVec1] > tmp[iVec2] )
    if ( sumSide >= round(n/2) ){
        count = count + 1
    } else if ( sumSide == 0 ){
        count = count + 1
    }
}
print(100*count/nSim)
```

which yields a probability close to 1.5%. However, the analytic result yields a probability around 0.45%, which is approx. a factor three off. Is this an artefact of the non-true randomness of the used random numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with R's PRNG, but with the logic used to conduct Nelson's fourth test.

Consider the simple case `tmp <- 1:14`:

```
count = 0
n     = 14
iVec1 = seq(1, n, by=2)
iVec2 = iVec1 + 1
tmp   = 1:n
sum(tmp[iVec1] > tmp[iVec2])
#> [1] 0
```

This would have incorrectly incremented `count` in the OP's script. Instead we can do:

```
nSim <- 1e7L
n <- 14L
sum(colSums(abs(diff(sign(diff(matrix(rnorm(n*nSim), n)))))) == 2L*(n - 2L))/nSim
#> [1] 0.0045829
```

Which is consistent with the [known analytical result](https://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1060&context=cssmwp) of $\frac{398721962}{14!}\approx0.00457$